# Angular unit test - Karma Jasmine - CLI is blank - karma-result xml is not generated

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

The test case progress shown in CLI is inconsistent. On developer's local machines, it seems to be working fine. However, when the test builds are run in servers (Windows / Linux), we see that most of the time the CLI doesn't show the progress but begins to scroll with blank content and after sometime, the final result `TOTAL: 1175 SUCCESS` is shown.

```
-"@angular/core": "8.2.14",
-"istanbul-combine": "0.3.0",
-"jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
-"jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
-"karma": "4.1.0",
-"karma-browserify": "6.1.0",
-"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
-"karma-cli": "2.0.0",
-"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.1",
-"karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
-"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.0",
-"karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
-"karma-parallel": "0.3.1",
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the libraries, angular, angular-cli, are the same on server and on local machine? Are you running the tests with exactly same parameters?

Comment: Yes. They are in sync.